# Does `hi link XXX Normal` provide any benefits?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, highlight

Does `hi link XXX Normal` provide any benefits? For example the syntax file included by default `syntax/vim.vim` includes the line:

```
hi def link vimUserFunc Normal
```

This often conflicts with `CursorLine` highlighting since `Normal` often sets a different background color than `CursorLine` e.g.

```
hi Normal guifg=#ffffff guibg=#000000
hi CursorLine guibg=#111111
```

Removing the link does not seem to have any immediately obvious adverse effects.

Are there any benefits that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a highlight, it could be highlighted by a different syntax group that might contain it.  My guess is that `vimUserFunc` was meant to look like normal text so it wouldn't be highlighted like built-in functions.

If by removing it, you mean deleting the line in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/vim.vim`, you shouldn't.  You can clear it with `:highlight clear vimUserFunc` in a script like `after/syntax/vim.vim`.  I doubt this will be the only occurrence of this, though.

> This often conflicts with CursorLine highlighting since Normal often sets a different background color than CursorLine e.g.

Getting `CursorLine` to look "right" is an uphill battle.  By default `Normal` isn't set.  Most of the stock themes don't actually set a background for anything unless its meant to stand out (e.g. `Error`, `Search`, etc.), in which case, inconsistency with the `CursorLine` background shouldn't be a concern.

If anything, setting a background color on `Normal` is creating your issue.